# What is the effect of the following CSS in a phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

What is the effect of including the following CSS? Initially this may seem like a silly question, but bear with me. I have the following page. Nothing too complicated, just a fixed header at the top with the h1 centered horizontally inside the header div. In a browser this works perfectly. However, this is to be used inside a phonegap 2.9.0 app.

On a nexus 4, when the screen rotates, the h1 is no longer centered horizontally **unless** the "orientations from js" css is included. But I don't even have the class in the @media selector in my HTML page at all. Admittedly I copied the orientation css from jquery mobile's css file, but only to understand how they were able to get their h1 to always center even upon device orientation change. **I am not using jquery mobile.**

Can someone please explain this mystery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>&nbsp;</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
/*CSS WITH THE CORRECTING EFFECT*/
@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
.nonExistantClass {}
}
/* OR THIS ONE! */
@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
.anotherNonExistantClass {}
}
/*END CSS WITH THE CORRECTING EFFECT*/

.header h1{
    font-size:1.4em;
    margin: 0 30%;
}
.header {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    height:2.4em;
    line-height:2.4em;
    text-align:center;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:
I have narrowed it down a bit. My initial question was about classes ui-mobile and ui-page. However the same CSS from before with changed class names has the exact same effect.

Further, I only need one of the two @media selectors to exhibit the mentioned behaviour. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

My answer, unless someone can correct me, is that this is simply a bug in phonegap or its implementation on Android, and that by including one of those media selectors I am forcing the browser view of the app to somehow do a width calculation that it is supposed to be doing in any case.

I wonder if the people behind jQuery knew this or just coincidentally happened to have CSS that corrected the bug...